# Is there a place with list of (common) arguments against veganism?

Tags: veganism, outreach

I am curious whether there's a website or a list containing most arguments people have for not going vegan or the reason why they are against veganism (like plants have feelings, we need animal protein to be healthy etc..)

I think it would be useful to have this and before start building my own database, I'm wondering whether you are aware of such a list or a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware of at least one such site:

https://yourveganfallacyis.com/

[image]